# Oracle: Why am I getting Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name when database table exists?

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

### Background

I have a `NodeJS` server powered by `ExpressJS` that fetches data from Oracle database. I manage the database with `Oracle SQL Developer` tool. There is a database called `MCF01` created using `Database Configuration Assistant` with pluggable database also named `MCF01`.

I connect to it using `SYSTEM` and the admin password both inside `Oracle SQL Developer` tool and from my server: [image: Connection has no problem]

Now I created a table named `CM_ITM_ALL`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "SYS"."CM_ITM_ALL" ...
```

I can without a problem query inside `CM_ITM_ALL` from `Oracle SQL Developer` tool like so:
[image: query screenshot]

### Problem

I cannot execute the same query `SELECT ITM_NM FROM CM_ITM_ALL WHERE ITM_NUM='a800004'` using my nodejs server. What is the problem here?

Here is the error message from the Oracle via my server:

```sh
[Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist] {
  errorNum: 942,
  offset: 19
}
```

Table does exist. Connection is not a problem as it is giving out the table does not exist error. Otherwise it would give out wrong credentials error.

### What I tried

1. Appending SYS into the query: `SELECT ITM_NM FROM SYS.CM_ITM_ALL WHERE ITM_NUM='a800004'`
2. Quoting the table name inside the query to `SELECT ITM_NM FROM 'SYS'.'CM_ITM_ALL' WHERE ITM_NUM='a800004'`

### Dev environment

- Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0
- NodeJS v16.13.0
- ExpressJs 4.17.2
- [node-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/) 5.3.0
- Oracle SQL Developer 21.4.2

Comment: from your sqldev scrreenshot, it seems you are connected to the cdb root, and not the pdb. If nodejs is connecting to the pdb, then it will not see the table. And never use the SYS schema for your objects, always create your own schema and use it.

Comment: And in addition to comment by @gsalem, this also highlights why is is a bad idea to name your pdb the same as the cdb.  Actually, I didn't even know it was possible to do so.

Comment: One side comment: you really need to be using service names not SIDs to connect to DBs in this era.

Comment: @gsalem oh I see, so CDB is like a useless base database, and I need PDB to do the actual database stuff with my app? `And never use the SYS schema for your objects` do you mean SYS user by SYS schema?

Comment: Thank you, I created another PDB and linked it to my MCF01 container database with a new user. Then I recreated my tables inside the new PDB. Now nodejs is querying from it with no problem. Anyone cares to post it as an answer? I will gladly accept it.